# Why was Christ depicted in catacomb paintings either with or without a beard?

Tags: church-history, reference-request, art, iconography

And do you have any examples of frescoes of Christ with a beard?

Answer (score 2):

The reason that Christ was often pictured without a beard is that [beards were generally not worn in Roman times](https://uk.bulldogskincare.com/blogs/news/when-in-rome-the-ancient-history-of-traditional-shaving#). The artists tended to depict Christ according to their own sense of fashion rather than the tradition of first c. Judaism. Here are some examples where Christ was pictured with a beard.

[image]

Bust of Christ between Alpha and Omega, mid-5th century painting on the ceiling of [Commodilla Catacomb](https://jesus-artworks.weebly.com/catacombs.html)

[image]

[Christ and Pope St. Urban I](https://www.bridgemanimages.com/en-US/roman/christ-and-st-urban-fresco/fresco/asset/405172)

[image]

[Christ with two saints](https://www.througheternity.com/en/blog/art/catacombs-rome-history.html)

Comment: Thank you for an answer. These frescoes are too new, but they will be helpful for me anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Why was Christ depicted in catacomb paintings either with or without a beard?**

The Pagan Celsus ridiculed the Christian religion for having an ugly God around the year 180 AD.  Origen then cited Psalm 45:3: "Gird thy sword upon thy thigh, mighty one, with thy beauty and fairness" indefensible of Jesus being handsome! Later, the emphasis of the leading Christian thinkers changed; St. Jerome and St. Augustine of Hippo argued that Jesus must have been quite beautiful in face and body. For Augustine he was "beautiful as a child, beautiful on earth, beautiful in heaven."

The earliest depictions of Jesus within the Catacombs were depicting Jesus without a beard. These types of Catacomb art were not very numerous and were eventually started to disappear from the 300 AD onwards. By the sixth century, depictions of Jesus having a beard tended to be the norm.

Thus only the earliest depictions of Jesus in the Catacombs showed him without a beard. For example the [The Good Shepherd](https://www.worldhistory.org/image/10352/the-good-shepherd-catacombs-of-priscilla/) from the Catacombs of Priscilla.

[image]

> The depiction of Jesus in pictorial form dates back to early Christian art and architecture, as aniconism in Christianity was rejected within the ante-Nicene period. It took several centuries to reach a conventional standardized form for his physical appearance, which has subsequently remained largely stable since that time. Most images of Jesus have in common a number of traits which are now almost universally associated with Jesus, although variants are seen.
>
> The conventional image of a fully bearded Jesus with long hair emerged around AD 300, but did not become established until the 6th century in Eastern Christianity, and much later in the West. It has always had the advantage of being easily recognizable, and distinguishing Jesus from other figures shown around him, which the use of a cruciform halo also achieves. Earlier images were much more varied.
>
> The earliest surviving Christian art comes from the late 2nd to early 4th centuries on the walls of tombs belonging, most likely, to wealthy Christians in the catacombs of Rome, although from literary evidence there may well have been panel icons which, like almost all classical painting, have disappeared.
>
> Initially Jesus was represented indirectly by pictogram symbols such as the ichthys (fish), the peacock, or an anchor (the Labarum or Chi-Rho was a later development). The staurogram seems to have been a very early representation of the crucified Jesus within the sacred texts. Later personified symbols were used, including Jonah, whose three days in the belly of the whale pre-figured the interval between Christ's death and resurrection; Daniel in the lion's den; or Orpheus charming the animals. The image of "The Good Shepherd", a beardless youth in pastoral scenes collecting sheep, was the most common of these images, and was probably not understood as a portrait of the historical Jesus at this period. It continues the classical Kriophoros ("ram-bearer" figure), and in some cases may also represent the Shepherd of Hermas, a popular Christian literary work of the 2nd century.
>
> Among the earliest depictions clearly intended to directly represent Jesus himself are many showing him as a baby, usually held by his mother, especially in the Adoration of the Magi, seen as the first theophany, or display of the incarnate Christ to the world at large. The oldest known portrait of Jesus, found in Syria and dated to about 235, shows him as a beardless young man of authoritative and dignified bearing. He is depicted with close-cropped hair and wearing a tunic and pallium—the common male dress for much of Greco-Roman society, and similar to that found in the figure art in the Dura-Europos Synagogue. - [Depiction of Jesus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depiction_of_Jesus)

Some have ventured to state that a beardless Christ in the Roman Catacombs was because it was Roman custom for men to be clean shaven. If this were so (and I am not saying it is not) why do depictions of Jesus in [Dura Europos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dura-Europos), Syria (235 AD) show Jesus without a beard. Men in the Middle East had beards!

[image]

The Healing of the Paralytic is one of the oldest known depictions of Jesus, from the Syrian city of Dura Europos, dating from about 235!

Some scholars try to link the idea of Christ having been depicted with a beard to the Shroud of Turin!

> The similarity between the Shroud face and most of the depictions of Christ known in art, both Eastern and Western, is clear and cannot be attributed to pure chance; it must be the result of a dependency, mediated or immediate, of an image from the other and of all from a common source. We can identify several elements on the Shroud that are not regular, hardly attributable to the imagination of the artists, that make us understand how the ancient representations of Christ's face depend on the venerated relic. It is reasonable to think that in the early days of the Church, the Shroud has been kept hidden for various reasons. During this period, for the representation of Christ they only used symbols or they applied to the figure of Christ appearances derived from other religions. After the victory of Christianity, sanctioned by Constantine in 313 with the Edict of Milan, a new image of the face of Jesus began to spread, which is characterized by not too long beard, mustache, narrow, tall and stately face, with long hair, falling on His shoulders, and sometimes with a middle line that divides them. Numerous testimonials, both written and iconographic, confirm that in Edessa (Şanliurfa today, in south-eastern Turkey) there was an impression left by Jesus on a cloth with His sweat and His blood. This sacred cloth, hidden for centuries and rediscovered in the sixth century, became the inspirational model for the iconography of Christ. All the legends, the traditions, the references to the existence of such an image are important for reconstructing an itinerary of the Shroud in the dark ages prior to its appearance in Europe and to understand why there are so many references to the existence of an image of Christ on a cloth. - [The Shroud and the iconography of Christ](https://www.shroud.com/pdfs/stlemarinellipaper.pdf)